# Which object and where should we use to fix this error?

Tags: c#, instagram, instagram-api

I'm getting an error when trying to change profile with C# Instagram API ( `System.NullReferenceException`)

```
using InstagramApiSharp;
using InstagramApiSharp.API;
using InstagramApiSharp.Classes;
using InstagramApiSharp.API.Builder;
using InstagramApiSharp.Logger;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WinFormsApp1

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private static IInstaApi api;
        private static UserSessionData user;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = "****";
            string password = "*****";
            user = new UserSessionData();
            user.UserName = username;
            user.Password = password;
            api = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder().SetUser(user).UseLogger(new DebugLogger(LogLevel.Exceptions)).Build();


            var picturePath = @"C:\Users\Rado\Desktop\download.jpg";
            var pictureBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(picturePath);
            var result =  api.AccountProcessor.ChangeProfilePictureAsync(pictureBytes);

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I was waiting for her to change her Instagram profile photo

Comment: `ChangeProfilePictureAsync(...)` sounds like you should `await` it in an `async` method (what is the actual type of `result`?)